# Generic message dispatch using base class, how to (or should I) avoid dynamic_cast

Tags: c++, observer-pattern, producer-consumer

I am trying to create a generic message dispatching system. The reasons or objectives I am trying to acheive are:

1. Remove the need for producers and consumers to "know" about each other.
2. Multiple consumers multiple producers
3. Interchange log file of messages and real system. Replay data easily.

My initial design is something like below with each message type has a unique integer number (1/2/3/4). This allows consumers to subsribe to the dispatch system, and lookup is just "for all consumers at index N". The reason for the message ID is the messages will be: 1) logged (binary format), 2) re-processed/replayed, and 3) sent over a network to other devices. So they need to be identified from binary form.

The problem I am having a hard time with is, I can easily pass base classes around. But consumers want concrete types. Right now im using dynamic cast, but online forums say its a sign of code "smell", but Im stuck on how to do this type of design without all consumers needing to know of producers, or having "dispatchers" for each message type (I have around 40 different messages).

```
class BaseMsg {
public:
  BaseMsg() {}
  virtual ~BaseMsg() = default;
  virtual int Id() const = 0;
}
class MyMsg0 : public BaseMsg {
public:
  double GetDouble() const {return my_double;}
  int Id() const {return 0;}
  void DoSomethingOnlyMsg0CanDo() {};
private:
  double my_double;
};
class MyMsg1 : public BaseMsg {
public:
  int GetInt() const {return my_int;}
  int Id() const {return 1;}
  void DoSomethingOnlyMsg1CanDo() {};
private:
  int my_int;
};
typedef void (*msg_callback)(class BaseMsg* msg);
/* This would normally hold callbacks that get called when producers produce msg1/2
  would be a 2d array to hold N message types and M number of observers */
static all_callbacks msg_callbacks[2];

int main() {
  /* Somewhere in some code a message 1 is generated, they would call a method like this */
  Message1 msg1;
  dispatch_message(msg1);
  /* Then in dispatch_message(BaseMsg& msg) all consumers of this message ID get called */
  msg_callbacks[msg.Id()](msg);
  /* In the consumer code consume_msg1(BaseMsg& msg) which is the callback in msg_callbacks */
  register_message(consume_msg1);
  // In consume_msg1(msg) callback
  Message1 msg1 = dynamic_cast<BaseMsg&>(msg);
  msg1.DoSomethingOnlyMsg1CanDo();
  msg1.GetInt();

  /* Repeats elsewhere in code for message 0...N */
  Messag0 msg0 = dynamic_cast<BaseMsg&>(msg);
  msg0.DoSomethingOnlyMsg0CanDo();
  msg0.GetDouble();
}
```

Comment: Why does the consumer think it can `DoSomethingOnlyMsg1CanDo`  if it may be receiving a message of a different type?

Comment: @jtbandes that is correct, I would like the consumer to actually be my_callback(concrete_type msg) but not sure how I can do that with registering generic callback?
Ideally the consumer should register only for the ID they want, and get callbacked only on that ID.

Comment: You may be interested in reading through the design of ROS's subscription mechanism: https://github.com/strawlab/ros_comm/blob/6f7ea2feeb3c890699518cb6eb3d33faa15c5306/clients/cpp/roscpp/include/ros/node_handle.h#L337-L339 where a subscriber specifies the type they are subscribing to and the internal infrastructure ensures messages are only delivered if they are of the correct type.

Comment: What is the full definition of `msg_callbacks` (using `all_callbacks` instead of `msg_callback` suggests there might be more structure than is in the question)? Do you ever need to access more than one element of `msg_callbacks` (e.g. `msg_callbacks[msg.Id()](msg);` accesses only one element of the array)? In short, I am asking you to justify your use of an array here.